# Making ui look like "always on screen in samsung"

Tags: android, xml, android-designer

I want to make a UI that looks like. There will be text in the center of the screen and no background. All of these pixels must be closed. Is there any way to do it?

Not: I don't mean changing the background to black. This way, the black area still has light.
[image: always on screen example]

Comment: Are you trying to create this layout using XML ?

Comment: Show your code please...

Comment: @Rajasekhar this is not related to XML design. My question is about closing pixel light.

Comment: @Hafiza , there is no code. I have asked, how do we do? Or is it possible?